# How to create QT version for arm-linux-generic-elf-32

Tags: qt, qmake

> In my debian linux (with i386 processor).i installed QT creator thats works fine.Also i installed G++ cross compiler to run over another system which is having Debian linux with ARM processor.
>
> Now in QT creator "Tools->Options->Build&Run-->Compilers" i added G++ compiler thats also using "Add" option that also fine.
>
> Now in QT creator "Tools->Options->Build&Run-->Kits" i added new Kit with Name as "G++"  , device type as "Desktop" , compiler as "G++ (above step added compiler)" thats also fine.
>
> The problem here is in QT version option.In my QT version option having "QT 5.5.0 GCC 64bit" only. If i select that option it is showing the error because G++ compiler is "arm-linux-generic-elf-32 bit".
>
> It is showing the error like , "The compiler G++ (arm-linux-generic-elf-32 bit) cannot produce code for the QT version QT 5.5.0 GCC 64bit (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit)" . 
>   For me the executable file only enough, no need to run on target directly.
>
> Guide me how to add QT version for arm-linux-generic-elf-32bit

Comment: Check the [Officially Supported Platforms](http://doc.qt.io/QtSupportedPlatforms/) to see the platforms on which Qt has been compiled and tested, and which compiler they used.

Comment: @agold: Hi agold, Thanks for previous question guidance , i installed sucessfully QT creator :) . The official supported platform also having "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4.1" compiler. i installed it ,now im looking to configure it

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Finally I found my mistake:

In menu:
QTCreator/Extras/Einstelungen/Compiler
(I guess it is QTCreator/Tools/Setting/Compiler in English.)

I clicked button Hinzufuegen ("Add") and then Benutzerdefiniert ("User defined") and that was wrong. It is to be: CCG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Afterwards I had to set up also so called ABI to "arm-linux-generic-elf-32 bit"

Then I had a problem with Qt Versionen - it made its own and I could not delete it. So in "Kits" I inserted the new Qt Version.

It works somehow now... 
Sort of crazy...

Answer (score 0):

Select your custom kit, change `Qt version` to `None`. This is Windows screenshot, but it's same on Linux. If you have `Qt version` which config corresponds to your kit's compiller you can choose it instead `None`
[image]